Axis2 Web Service Not Displaying on localhost:2525/axis2/services/listServices
i have an issue with eclipse and axis2
sorry if my explanation is bad.
so im trying to make a simple web service for MainServiceClass class
i created the web service for it and everything looks good but when i run the project
the page localhost:2525/Axis2WSTest gives 404 error and when i go localhost:2525/axis2/services/listServices my service not showing up but in file explorer i can see MainServiceClass listed in webapp/WEB-INF/services
did i miss something while installing tomcat and axis2 or its just a simple issue?
sry for wasting ur times , I'm new and I've been trying to solve this for the last couple of hours .
project facets
Structure
Axis2WSTest service page
Axis2 Services Page
MainServiceClass.java:
package com.jsp;

public class MainServiceClass {

    public int somme(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

those are my project files On Github
